# Interest Rate Swap DV01

Tags: swaps, interest-rate-swap, duration

thank you in advance anyways! I do have a question that drives me mad.

How do i calculate the Swap DV01 for a Interest Rate Swap?

I think for a bond i multiply the discounted cashflows times the point in time, and divide it through the bond price to end up with duration and thus i can end up with dollar value of 1 bp.

But for a european IRS i do not know.

I think there exists the cash formula, but this suggests a flat interest curve which is not applicable.

KR and thanks everybody!

Comment: [This answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/70426/54838) shows how bumping the interest rate curves is used in Bloomberg to compute DV01 and shows manual calculation from cashflows.

Answer (score 1):

you can calc it as the difference in npv you get when you bump the yield curve and calc your npv , vs your original npv

Comment: agreed, so many times people conflate a dv01 with the present value of a basis point annuity - it's almost that, but not quite (particularly important when u generalise to eg credit risky swaps)